# Oracle: create a partition by reference (partition by reference(fk)) on non referenced table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

We have realized that we need to use Oracle (12 c) interval partitioning.We have an hierarchical entity model with lots of @OneToMany relationships.We want to use "partitioning by range" (day,month... ) on the "parent/root" entity (A) and "partition by reference" on all child entities (B).
From the Oracle documentation: "Reference partitioning allows the partitioning of two tables related to one another by referential constraints. The partitioning key is resolved through an existing parent-child relationship, enforced by enabled and active primary key and foreign key constraints." The problem is that child entities (B) can refer to other entities ( C) that they don't have any link with the "parent/root" entity (A). I can create partitions on A and on B but when I want to drop the partition on A ( partition on B on cascade), I get an error integrity error and it fails. it works only if I delete all records on C and B and then partition them. I don't want to do that as it's not efficient and slow compared to dropping partitions directly

**Please is there a way to create a partition on table C based on A(creation_date) without adding any foreign constraint between A and C?**

Small example to illustrate the case

```
A - parent entity
B - child entity to A
C - child entity to  B

create table 
A (
   id number primary key,
   creation_date date
)
partition by range (creation_date) 
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
(
   partition p1 values less than (to_date('20180501','yyyymmdd'))
);

create table 
B (
   id number primary key,
   value varchar2(5),
   a_id number not null,
   constraint fk_ba foreign key (a_id) references A
)
partition by reference(fk_ba);

create table 
C (
   id number primary key,
   code varchar2(5),
   b_id number not null,
   constraint fk_cb foreign key (b_id) references B
);
```

Comment: please ask a question with your title.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it? Please what do you mean?

Comment: It's a better practice to change your title into a question phrase. Your question will get more views if it will have a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear in the documentation that partition by reference is transitive ( A->B->C). I have discovered it by testing. we can create table C "partition by reference (fk_cb)" with the result that when we drop A partition the matching B and C partitions get dropped.